# Как передать ивент о том что была нажата кнопка?

Tags: vue.js

Можно ли ивент о том, что была нажата кнопка, которая находится в родительском компоненте, передать дочернему?

Comment: Через `props` - да. На стороне дочернего отлавливать через `watch` изменение.

Comment: Можно и проще - напрямую обратиться к дочернему элементу: $refs.child.handleClick()

Comment: Благодарю!!!!!!